# Html tags get stripped in full html when "Correct faulty and chopped off HTML" is on

Tags: input-formats

All my html tags get stripped when I input html in "FULL HTML" mode. I have tried the simplest correct html I could think of:

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
```

still the html gets stripped resulting in plain text. This happens wether I add the html in an article, a basic page or a custom panel pane content.

The problem gets solved if I uncheck the "Correct faulty and chopped off HTML" filter In Configuration->Content authoring->Text formats->full html. In that case the html tags are not stripped and the content displays correctly. But I would like to keep this "Correct faulty and chopped off HTML" filter on. What am I missing?

I am using drupal 7.26

Thanks baba

Comment: What version is you MySQL and php?

Comment: What are all the filters you have enabled for full html? Is the problem happening when viewing a node page or is the content being viewed somewhere else? Can you post an example of the content you are entering when you see this problem?

Comment: @Kari this is happening on my local server with MySql 5.1.44 and PHP 5.3.1 (XAMMP 1.7.3 beta 1). I tried on my remote server with mysql 5.5.36 and php 5.4.24 and the problem disapears. I will try upgrading my local xammp to a newer version see if that helps.

Comment: @rooby enabled filters are: "Convert URLs into links", "Convert line breaks into HTML (i.e. <br> and <p>)", and  "Correct faulty and chopped off HTML". The latter being the one causing the problem. The problem is happening on nodes (i tried basic pages and articles) and also in custom panel panes. I think this is happening everywhere. As for an example of the content: <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a> is an example.

Comment: Do you have any other broken markup on the page that might be interfering? For example if your node is wrapped in a link and you have a link in the node it will make invalid markup and strange things will happen. You could try http://validator.w3.org/ on your page. I also find firefox quite good for this. If you view source in firefox (ctrl+u) it will colour broken html tags red, which can help find broken markup.